# MediaCapture StartPreviewAsync fails

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime, media, uwp

I am trying to start video preview capture from the camera in my UWP app but StartPreviewAsync throws an exception

Sample Code:

```
MediaCapture mc = new MediaCapture();
await mc.InitializeAsync();
await mc.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs because currently StartPreviewAsync requires a sink to output frames to. This can be fixed by creating a capture element in xaml to display the frames.

```
<CaptureElement Name="captureElement"/>
```

now code can be updated to display the preview to the screen

```
MediaCapture mc = new MediaCapture();
await mc.InitializeAsync();
captureElement.Source = mc;
await mc.StartPreviewAsync();
```

If you want to start the preview without displaying anything to the screen you can create the captureElement in your app logic without adding to the view.

```
var captureElement = new CaptureElement();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! This mechanism is extremely counter-intuitive. =/